# Не получается запушить изменения на удаленный репозиторий

Tags: git, контроль-версий, git-push

Форкнул сборку, склонировал на компьютер.
После этого работал удаленно. Теперь хочу отправить сделанные комиты.

Выполнил команду `push`:

```
git push --set-upstream origin master
```

После выполнения этой команды появляется следующее:

```
     ! [rejected]        master -> master (fetch first)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/monsara/generator-hub.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

После выполнения данной команды появляется следующий текст:

```
here is no tracking information for the current branch.
Please specify which branch you want to merge with.
See git-pull(1) for details.

    git pull <remote> <branch>

If you wish to set tracking information for this branch you can do so with:

    git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/<branch> master

pertinent:generator-hub macbook$
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как отправить все коммиты на [удаленный репозиторий](https://github.com/monsara/generator-hub)?

И как можно защититься от возможной потери данных?

Comment: Кстати, а что у вас выводит команда `git remote -v` ?

Comment: Походу вы делали `git pull` без указания репо и ветки. На это вам git дал подсказку "Please specify which branch you want to merge with.", но вы не вчитались в этот текст. Вам нужно указать репо и ветку. А  @AivanF. вам правильно сказал: гляньте какие у вас ветки есть через `git remote -v`. Думаю, ваша проблема решится через `git pull origin master`, если все правильно настроено. `И как можно защититься от возможной потери данных?`. В гите все уже есть. Вы не потеряете ничего, если умышленно не будете делать этого. Если запутаетесь в своих действиях, `git reflog`, затем `git checkout` и т.д.

Comment: Благодарю. Решил проблему следующим образом - удалил удаленный репозиторий, создал еще один с таким же названием и запушил в него.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Судя по выводу, мастер на сервере ушёл по коммитам дальше, и автомерж сделать никак, поэтому просто пуш не работает. Получилась ситуация вроде этой:

[image: Диаграмма коммитов]

Что делать:

1. Подтянуть изменения в локальный мастер, `git pull`
2. Разрешить конфликты, гит о них сообщит
3. Запушить слитую ветку на удалённый мастер, `git push`

Чтобы не потерять текущие данные, можно заранее локальный мастер сохранить в отдельную локальную ветку в качестве бекапа, `git checkout -b backup`. Или даже запушить на сервер как отдельную ветку, чтобы всё точно было в сохранности.

---

PS: советую почитать теоретические материалы по теме, вот хорошая статья: [Ветвление в Git – Удалённые ветки](https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v2/%D0%92%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2-Git-%D0%A3%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%91%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B8)

Comment: Дело в том что, когда выполняю команду git pull получаю следующее: pertinent:generator-hub macbook$ git pull
There is no tracking information for the current branch.
Please specify which branch you want to merge with.
See git-pull(1) for details.

    git pull <remote> <branch>

If you wish to set tracking information for this branch you can do so with:

    git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/<branch> master

Comment: Может можно создать новы удаленный гит репозиторий и привязать к нему локальный и запушить комиты?

Comment: @ViktorHirenko Я написал вопрос в комментарии выше, что выводит команда `git remote -v` ?? Возможно репозиторий не имеет ссылки на серверную ветку. Если она всё же есть, должна сработать команда `git pull origin master`

Comment: Благодарю. Я так делал и решил вопрос описанным выше способом